# strange date from uidatepicker

Tags: iphone, ipad

I use date picker and I set its mode to be

```
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate ;
```

when select august 3o, 2011

to display It I use

```
NSDate * selected = [pickerView date];
NSString * date = [selected description];
DateLabel.text = date;
```

the output is `2011-08-29 21:00:00:00 + 0000`

any suggestion on how to display the correct date only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

try using:

```
NSDate *selected = [pickerView date];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setDateStyle: kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:selected];
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD/MM/yyyy"];//you can change format here @"MM/yyyy"
DateText.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
[dateFormatter release];
```